# Solved: Method association in python dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have to maintain code which uses dataclasses. In these, methods from libraries are imported and associated and I find the way it's done confusing and not very readable. It's done like this (a very simplified example) :

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from code.custom.package import method_a, method_b

@dataclass
class myClass:
    import numpy as np
    var1: str
    var2: str
    var3: np.ndarray = None

myClass.method_a = method_a
myClass.method_b = method_b
```

The methods generally do operations on the data structures contained in the class.

Is this a common practice ? Is this the proper way to do this ? Or should this be avoided and done in another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing here is good practice. Let's break it down piece-by-piece

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from code.custom.package import method_a, method_b
```

This is fine. `dataclasses` is modern and useful. Some people will prefer to put each imported symbol on its own line like

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from code.custom.package import method_a
from code.custom.package import method_b
```

but I wouldn't call that a universal practice.

```
@dataclass
class myClass:
```

We have a `dataclass`. That means we get `__eq__`, a nice constructor, and a good string representation for free. The class name is weird, by basically all standards. Usually, we name classes in `StudlyCaps`, and there are no names in Python which use the `camelCase` convention (except really old standard library modules like `logging`). So that immediately strikes me as weird.

```
    import numpy as np
```

This is an extremely weird place for an import. Imports almost always go at the top of the file. Occasionally, you'll see them inside a top-level `if` statement for configuration-specific features (maybe a support library that's only needed on Windows, for instance). And *very* occasionally, you'll see imports at the beginning of a function for functionality needed only in that function (though I generally try to avoid that). Putting it in the class is just bizarre. It will always be evaluated unconditionally, so it should definitely be at the top of the file.

```
    var1: str
    var2: str
```

Okay, nothing to see here. Two required variables of type `str`. Fine by me.

```
    var3: np.ndarray = None
```

This will fail any reputable type checker. We stated that the type of this variable is `np.ndarray` but assigned it the value `None`, which is distinctly *not* a Numpy array.

If `None` is a valid value for this field, we should write `var3: np.ndarray | None = None` or `var3: Optional[np.ndarray] = None`. Or if we just don't care about the type checking, we should write `var3: Any = None` (`Optional` and `Any` come from the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module).

```
myClass.method_a = method_a
myClass.method_b = method_b
```

And now the main point of your question. That's also extremely weird. The only time I've ever seen real Python code assign fields outside of the class like this is if the field is of the class type. So something like

```
class MyClass:
    ...

MyClass.SINGLETON = MyClass(...)
```

where the class needs to fully exist and be defined in order to define the field. Assigning methods in this way is just plain bizarre. It would be slightly less weird if you wrote

```
class MyClass:
    method_a = imported_method_a
    method_b = imported_method_b
```

and honestly, I *think* most Python type checkers would accept that, since function objects are perfectly valid descriptors. I still wouldn't choose to write it this way, but it would be less weird. As mentioned in mattiatantardini's answer, these common methods should probably be in a superclass somewhere, possibly an [abstract class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) but maybe just a mixin. Then you can *inherit* that class in your own (dataclasses play very well with inheritance, especially compared to their primitive predecessor, namedtuples).

So, in summary, no, this code is not conventional Python, and I'm sorry you have the displeasure of having to maintain it. If your culture permits it, you could probably make a lot of improvements to this code.

The only place I can think of where it's normal to assign methods outside the class like that is really, really old Javascript. If you're writing Javascript fifteen years ago (before `class`es existed in JS), then you would define a constructor function `MyClass` and then assign methods on `MyClass.prototype` outside the constructor. It's possible that whoever wrote this code is a Javascript programmer from the year 2010. It's also possible they were just in a hurry.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is common and best practice to define class methods in this way.

IMHO, if the same `method_a` and `method_b` are reused in different modules and classes, a better choice would be to create a parent class which implements these two methods and than inherit from it two create new classes like the one you display.

This makes the methods reusable with different inputs, which I guess are the variables defined in the constructor of the class.

**PS**: it is also best practice to put all imports at the top of the module, if there is no special need to do otherwise (as it seems in your case).